# Иероглифы при добавлении записи в БД с хостинга

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Пишу сайт развернув его на локальном веб сервере. Для взаимодействия с БД использую не локальную БД, а БД ранее купленного хостинга.
При добавлении записей в БД с локального сервера все записи добавляются верно и запросы отображаются верно.
При добавлении записей в БД с хостинга, русский текст в них добавляется иероглифами, но на страницах сайта при запросе из бд отображается нормально. Ранее добавленные записи с локального веб сервера на хостинге отображаются знаками вопроса.
Перепробовал варианты из гугла - ничего не меняется.
В чем может быть проблема?
Кодировка всех таблиц и всех полей в них utf8_general_ci.

Comment: смотрите на кодировку базы данных, таблиц, полей, страниц сайта, стороннего ПО. Не совсем понятно из вопроса как вы добавляете данные и которые из данных неверно отображаются

Comment: @ArchDemon на моем сайте есть конструктор страниц. После создания страницы в БД добавляется информация об этой странице. Вот эта самая информация отображается иероглифами в БД, но верно на веб страницах, если ее добавить с хостинга.
А если пытаться запросить из БД информацию, которая там была ранее (она была добавлена в нее же с локального сервера), то она выводится знаками вопроса, хотя в самой БД все корректно

Comment: "Вот эта самая информация отображается иероглифами в БД" чем вы смотрите данные в БД? У вас 100% проблема с кодировкой

Comment: @ArchDemon через phpmyadmin на хостинге я смотрю

Comment: phpmyadmin показывает кодировку бд (таблицы, столбцы), кодировку подключения к бд. Если там всё нормально, то проблема в вашем коде. У вас файлы скриптов (php код) в utf-8? у вас нас странице сайта есть тег `meta` с указанием кодировки?

Comment: @ArchDemon На той странице, на которой выводится текст - да

http://skrinshoter.ru/s/280320/ybReqLXa
Но нужно видимо где то еще указывать кодировки, чтобы верно записывалось в БД

Comment: Сами файлы php должны быть в utf-8. При подключении к БД неплохо указывать кодировку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106043/discussion-between---and-archdemon).